# Yeast rolls spread when rising

Tags: yeast, rolls

I make yeast roll dough in my bread machine, then form them into rolls and let them rise. They are delicious but when rising they seem to spread out and not rise very high. What can I do to make them taller?

Comment: See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/42936/67

Comment: Although the dough type is different, the technique described in the other question will work the same way for yeast dough.

Answer (score 2):

Most baked rolls are placed closer together to encourage rising, and limiting horizontal spreading.

Answer (score 1):

If you're making a soft dough, the rolls need to be placed closed enough together to support each other for the final rise and baking.  Or you could make individual rolls in muffin tins if you're looking for a soft roll with a crispy crust. For hard rolls, it may be that your bread machine doesn't need the dough enough to form adequate gluten...the gluten is what will give the dough structure.  Try starting the kneading in the machine and then kneading by hand with a little extra flour.  The dough should be very elastic when you finish kneading.  Good baking.

Answer (score -1):

Food Lover is quite right, although other issues may be that:

1. the liquid you used wasn't warm enough (cold inhibits yeast activity; consequently, too-hot liquid will also prevent proper rising)
2. too much salt was used
3. too much sugar, or not enough was used
4. check expiration date on yeast packet

Comment: These hints are helpful for non-rising dough, but OP reports that their rolls rise, but spread too much.